# Accelerated C++ 14-5: Custom string class and reference counter works for one constructor but not another

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, accelerated-c++

For those of you familiar with the book Accelerated C++, I was writing a solution to problem 14-5 and came across some interesting behavior that I can't explain.

The problem involves using custom string and pointer/reference counter classes to implement a program that can concatenate vectors of strings and create pictures out of them.

Essentially, the part of the program in question is the following:

```
int main()
{
    vec<str> test;
    str s;

    while(getline(std::cin,s))
    {
            test.push_back(str(s.begin(),s.end()));
            //test.push_back(s); // This line doesn't work here - why?

            // Using the above line results in every str in test being 
            // the empty string
    }

    // Use the vec<str> to make pictures

}
```

It seems as though my reference counter isn't working properly when I use the commented line: the result I get is as if every `str` in `test` were the empty string.

Here are my implementations of `getline` and the relevant parts of the `str` and `ptr` classes:

`str` class:

```
class str
{
    friend std::istream& getline(std::istream &is, str &s);

public:
    typedef char* iterator;
    typedef const char* const_iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;

    str() : data(new vec<char>) { }
    str(size_type n, char c) : data(new vec<char>(n,c)) { }

    str(const char *cp) : data(new vec<char>)
    {
            std::copy(cp,cp+std::strlen(cp),std::back_inserter(*data));
    }

    template <class InputIterator>
    str(InputIterator b, InputIterator e) : data(new vec<char>)
    {
            std::copy(b,e,std::back_inserter(*data));
    }

    // Other str member functions and operators
private:
    ptr< vec<char> > data;
};
```

`ptr` class:

```
template <class T>
class ptr
{
public:
    void make_unique()
    {
            if(*refptr != 1)
            {
                    --*refptr;
                    refptr = new std::size_t(1);
                    p = p ? clone(p) : 0;
            }
    }

    ptr() : p(0), refptr(new std::size_t(1)) { }
    ptr(T* t) : p(t), refptr(new std::size_t(1)) { }

    ptr(const ptr &h) : p(h.p), refptr(h.refptr) { ++*refptr; }
    ptr& operator=(const ptr &);
    ~ptr();

    T& operator*() const
    {
            if(p)
            {
                    return *p;
            }

            throw std::runtime_error("unbound ptr");
    }

    T* operator->() const
    {
            if(p)
            {
                    return p;
            }

            throw std::runtime_error("unbound ptr");
    }

private:
    T* p;
    std::size_t* refptr;
};

template <class T>
ptr<T>& ptr<T>::operator=(const ptr &rhs)
{
    ++*rhs.refptr;
    // free the left hand side, destroying pointers if appropriate
    if(--*refptr == 0)
    {
            delete refptr;
            delete p;
    }

    // copy in values from the right-hand side
    refptr = rhs.refptr;
    p = rhs.p;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
ptr<T>::~ptr()
{
    if(--*refptr == 0)
    {
            delete refptr;
            delete p;
    }
}
```

The `vec` class is essentially a subset of `std::vector`. I can supply those details here too, if necessary.

And here is getline:

```
std::istream& getline(std::istream &is, str &s)
{
    s.data->clear();
    char c;
    while(is.get(c))
    {
        if(c != '\n')
        {
            s.data->push_back(c);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

return is;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are counting references correctly, you are still sharing the same pointer between the instances. So `getline` is modifying the same `str` object. You need to implement [Copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) in `str`.

Here is what's wrong:

```
std::istream& getline(std::istream &is, str &s)
{
    s.data->clear();          //should make a copy of data first
    char c;
    while(is.get(c))
    {
        if(c != '\n')
        {
            s.data->push_back(c);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

return is;
}
```

So, you should do:

```
s.data = ptr(new vec<char>());
```

instead of clearing the shared instance.

Comment: @BartoszKP If data already has some old info I would want to get rid of it first, so perhaps calling clear() and then new would be best? In other words, I do want getline to overwrite whatever happens to exist in s.

Comment: @Adam27X It's not "old" - it's shared among other instances of `str`. You do not want to get rid of it. Getting rid of it is what is your problem here. The `vec` will be deleted automatically if its reference counter goes to `0`.

Comment: @BartoszKP, where'd you get implementation of `getline`? I don't see it in the examples, unless I am blind...

Comment: @BartoszKP Thanks for the clarification. Indeed, this solution works. InnocentBystander, I've edited the question to make this clearer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

```
test.push_back(s); // This line doesn't work here - why?
```

now `s` and a copy of `s` in `test` share the same data. During the next iteration of the `while` loop `getline` function calls `s.data->clear()`, which clears data in **both** `s` and the copy of `s` in `test`.

When you call:

```
test.push_back(str(s.begin(),s.end()));
```

the `str(s.begin(),s.end())` constructor creates a temp `str` object with a copy of the data that was in `s` and pushes that object into `test`. So now the temp object and the copy in `test` share the same data, which is a non-shared copy of `s`. The temp object gets destroyed and the copy in `test` stays intact.